# Data compression SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have table with `PAGE` compression type, it's size is 7 GB. But when I use

```
sp_estimate_data_compression_savings 'dbo', 'tableName', null, null, 'PAGE'
```

it return's `size_with_requested_compression_setting - 3GB`, lower that current table size.

I don't understand why does space savings estimate in compressed table.

Table creation script:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[_AccumRgT2225](
    [_Period] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [_Fld2217RRef] [binary](16) NOT NULL,
    [_Fld5936RRef] [binary](16) NOT NULL,
    [_Fld2218RRef] [binary](16) NOT NULL,
    [_Fld5937RRef] [binary](16) NOT NULL,
    [_Fld2219] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [_Fld2220] [numeric](21, 2) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [_AccumR2225_ByDims_TRRRRT] ON [dbo].[_AccumRgT2225]
(
    [_Period] ASC,
    [_Fld2217RRef] ASC,
    [_Fld5936RRef] ASC,
    [_Fld2218RRef] ASC,
    [_Fld5937RRef] ASC,
    [_Fld2219] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Why are you running the procedure against a table that is already compressed? Did you compress only one index but not all and/or not the clustered index? Please generate a script for the table, including indexes, and show it.

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.